# org mode auto order

Tags: org-mode, todo

Is there any option/extension in org mode to auto order certain lists?

For example: I would like to order by TODOs by priority or I would like to order by TODOs by state.

Comment: Here is a complex of example of how to programmatically sort (by multiple criteria) a primary `org-mode` buffer using `org-sort-entries`, and refiling/moving subtrees to the proper main headings based on various criteria using `org-archive-subtree`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `org-sort`, which by default is mapped to `C-c ^` in `org-mode`:

> Sort same-level entries. When there is an active region, all entries in the region will be sorted. Otherwise the children of the current headline are sorted. The command prompts for the sorting method, which can be alphabetically, numerically, by time (first timestamp with active preferred, creation time, scheduled time, deadline time), by priority, by TODO keyword (in the sequence the keywords have been defined in the setup) or by the value of a property.

See this answer for multiple sorting levels: [org: How to sort headings by TODO and then by priority?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/org-how-to-sort-headings-by-todo-and-then-by-priority)