# Sorting todos by custom todo label when invoking `org-todo-list` with `C-c a t`

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, sorting, todo

I have defined some custom todos keywords with

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "TODAY" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "URGENT" "FUTURE" "MAYBE" "LATER" "DONE")))
```

And when I invoke `C-c a t` I see the following:

[image]

I would like the todos to appear in the following order:
`"URGENT" "TODAY" "IN-PROGRESS" "TODO" "WAITING" "FUTURE" "MAYBE" "LATER" "DONE"`
and then, within each distinct label, having the todos sorted by priority.

I have tried many approaches, especially [the one described here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/org-how-to-sort-headings-by-todo-and-then-by-priority), but nothing works for me.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Do you want this sorting *within* each category (today, learning, free_time)? Or across all the categories (IOW sort all the URGENTs and then within the URGENTs sort by category)?

Comment: I would actually like to learn how to code the different options. But the one that I will use will be: first sorting by tag (custom sorting), then by categories ("URGENT" > "TODAY" > ...) and finally, within each category, by priority (#A, #B, ...)

Comment: Just to clarify: the categories shown in your example are "today", "learning" and "free_time"; the todo entry tags are "URGENT, ..."DONE". So all the URGENTs for all categories/priorities are together first, then all the "TODAY"s etc. Within the URGENT group, first all the "today" entries, then all the "learrning" entries, (BTW, how is this order determined? above it seems reverse-alphabetically by category name, but you hate not specified). Then within each category (all the "today" entries within the URGENT group), sort by priority - correct?

Comment: Correct! With only one difference, I would prefer the entries (within the same entry tag value (TODO... DONE)), to be first sorted by tag priority (#A, #B, ...) and then by category.
I don't know in this case what is determining the order of the categories, but it would be cool if it could be specified.

Comment: So first by todo state, second by prioriry and third by category. Now it only remains to find somebody to implement it :-) I might be able to take a look in the next couple of weeks but no promises.